# Drawing multiple parallel lines using Vega

Tags: reactjs, visualization, vega

I'm currently using Vega to create a nodemap, is there a way to configue the connecting paths to show multiple colors depending on the common attributes between nodes? I.e. 2 common attributes -> 2 colored lines like shown:

[image: Line Colors]

How could I draw lines conditionally and shift the coordinates slightly so they appear separately?

Here's the spec I have so far:

```json
{
    "type": "path",
    "from": {"data": "links"},
    "interactive": true,
    "encode": {
        "update": {
            "stroke": {
                "signal": "(datum.source.datum.filmId == hoverLinkSource && datum.target.datum.filmId == hoverLinkTarget) || datum.source.datum.filmId == hoverNode || datum.target.datum.filmId == hoverNode  ? '#0aa4b5' : 'black'"
            },
            "strokeWidth": {"value": 3},
            "cursor": {"value": "pointer"},
            "tooltip": {"signal": "{'title': 'Film Link', 'Film 1': datum.source.datum.title, 'Film 2': datum.target.datum.title, 'Link': datum.label}"}
        }
    },
    "transform": [
        {
            "type": "linkpath",
            "require": {"signal": "force"},
            "shape": "line",
            "orient": "horizontal",
            "sourceX": "datum.source.x", "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
            "targetX": "datum.target.x", "targetY": "datum.target.y"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried drawing multiple paths but they don't stick together, rather branching out.
I'm using vega v5.

Comment: Can you share a full spec in the online vega editor?

Comment: yes: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/963693e9d9e397817b99ab7a49325af2/spec.json

Comment: There is no data in there so it cannot be debugged. However, it looks fairly standard. On my github, there is a network graph here which might give you some ideas about how to solve your problem. https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase?tab=readme-ov-file#force-direct-graph-dynamic

Comment: Thank you, it seems like I can use formulas to conditionally draw lines based on attributes but I'm not sure if linkpath can draw multiple lines between the same nodes? Can't seem to find any examples online...

Comment: You would need multiple linkpaths and have to calculate the start and end points yourself by manually offsetting them. I don't think it is trivial.

Comment: Or you could reuse the x and y values from the existing linkpath and have formulae based on those. I'm not sure how you would calculate offsets though.